# Linker error with or tools and STS/Eclipse

Tags: java, or-tools

I am running or tools with windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017. With command prompt, I could run test_java program or vrp.java from examples.

I'm trying to integrate or tools with STS/Eclipse.

I have also set native library path in STS and still I see below linker error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.ortools.constraintsolver.operations_research_constraint_solverJNI.swig_module_init()V
    at com.google.ortools.constraintsolver.operations_research_constraint_solverJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
    at com.google.ortools.constraintsolver.operations_research_constraint_solverJNI.<clinit>(operations_research_constraint_solverJNI.java:2379)
    at com.google.ortools.constraintsolver.RoutingModel.<clinit>(RoutingModel.java:652)
```

Can someone list down steps needed to successfully run ortools with STS on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Google search? :-)

You need to set the java library path to point to or-tools/lib.

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/